# Without primes in $P$ does integer factorization lie in $coNP$?

Tags: factoring, co-np

In integer factorization we ask 'Given $N$ is there a $a\in[2,\sqrt{N}+1]$ such that $a|N$?'.

Is the above problem in coNP because we know primes is in $P$?

That is there is no such factor $a$ of $N$ iff $N$ is prime and we have AKS certificate.

So was it not known prior to 2004 that integer factoring was in coNP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're misstating integer factorization: your version is completely equivalent to primality.

Second, there were [primality certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate) which could stand for a polytime primality testing algorithm. These are polytime verifiable certificates of primality.

Comment: thank you what is the correct definition of IF?

Comment: There are several possible definitions. One option is: given $n,i,j,b$, whether the $i$th smallest prime factor of $n$ has $j$th bit equal to $b$.

Comment: interesting.. so I am very confused why is my query in quotes wrong? I see it seems to equal primality but still not compltely clear.

Comment: Given $n$, you're asking whether it's prime (or a square).

Comment: That is true but Ok how about a different definition of IF? may be that will clear my confusion.

Comment: I already gave you one: the set of tuples $\langle n,i,j,b \rangle$ such that the $j$th bit of the $i$th smallest prime factor of $n$ is $b$.

Comment: That _is_ "the definition". ​ An equivalently-hard problem is: given $N,b$, is there a $a\in [2,b]$ such that $a|N$. ​ ​​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Thank you for the equivalent problem. That is more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Without primes in P does integer factorization lie in coNP? ​ [Yes.](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/gila-2-pratt-certificates-for-primality/)

So was it not known prior to 2004 that integer factoring was in coNP? ​ [No.](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/03/04/gila-2-pratt-certificates-for-primality/)

Comment: ok without reading blog I want to ask in short how do you show IF is in coNP without primes is in P?

Comment: Give [recursive certificates for the factorization of p-1] and a [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Generators) to show that the [multiplicative group mod p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) is cyclic of order p-1. ​ ​

Comment: Could you include some details in your answer, please?